# Hibernate Transaction Advice in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

My project is using Spring MVC4, Hibernate 5. I have configured hibernate transaction with Advice Interceptor, but it does not rollback as I would like. Please help me, what is the problem with my configuration?

All my code is as below:
**1. Hibernate config:**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class DataSourceConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                            new String[] {env.getProperty("spring.hibernate.packagesToScan")});
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

            return dataSource;
        }

       @Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
            return txManager;
        }

        @Bean
        public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
            return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
        }
    }
```

2. Spring Advice Interceptor:

   @Aspect
   @Configuration
   public class TxAdviceInterceptor {

   ```
   private static final String TX_METHOD_NAME = "*";

   @Value(value = "${tx-advice.timeout:-1}")
   private Integer txMethodTimeout = -1;

   private static final String AOP_POINTCUT_EXPRESSION =
                   "execution(* com.ptg.service..*.*(..))";

   @Autowired
   private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   @Bean
   public TransactionInterceptor txAdvice() {
       MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource source = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
       RuleBasedTransactionAttribute transactionAttribute = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute();
       transactionAttribute.setName(TX_METHOD_NAME);
       transactionAttribute.setRollbackRules(
                       Collections.singletonList(new RollbackRuleAttribute(Exception.class)));
       transactionAttribute.setTimeout(txMethodTimeout);
       source.setTransactionAttribute(transactionAttribute);
       return new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, source);
   }

   @Bean
   public Advisor txAdviceAdvisor() {
       AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
       pointcut.setExpression(AOP_POINTCUT_EXPRESSION);
       return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, txAdvice());
   }
   ```

   }
3. DAO:

   @Repository
   public abstract class GenericDaoImpl{

   ```
   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Override
   public void S save(S entity) {
       sessionFactory.save(entity);
   }
   ```

   }

DaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class TagDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl{
}

@Repository
public class PostDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl{
}
```

4. Service:

   @Service
   public class PostServiceImpl{

   ```
   @Autowired
   private PostDao postDao;

   @Autowired
   private TagDao tagDao;

   public void merge(Post post){
       tagDao.save();
       postDao.save();
   }
   ```

   }

As code above, I would like if postDao.save is error, tagDao is also rollback.

Comment: How do you intend to handle situations where you may need diferent propagation or isolation levels for a service method's transaction?  What about cases where a service method doesn't mandate the necessity of a transaction.  Be mindful that using `"*"` here can be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. My configuration is not wrong. 
The problem is "**Only unchecked exceptions (that is, subclasses of java.lang.RuntimeException) are rollbacked by default. For the case, a checked exception is thrown, the transaction will be committed**". 
I have test my code with NullPointerException error, therefore Transaction is not rollbacked.

Refer: https://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/spring-transactional-rollback-on-checked-exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried @Transactional annotation?

Comment: I don't want to use @Transactional annotation on each service.

Comment: My project has many services. Sometimes we forget the add @Transactional annotation, so the error has occurred

Comment: My idea is to use the advice interceptor of spring framework to auto open/ rollback transaction instead of @Transactional annotation.

Comment: I have found this, please search for the title 9.6.2. Using the PlatformTransactionManager on this link :
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic-ptm

Comment: I don't understand how to using the PlatformTransactionManager in this case. Can you explain more details for me, please?

Comment: I have found an example on the internet:
http://javahonk.com/spring-programmatic-transactions-by-platformtransactionmanager/

Seems like everytime you are about to do something in the database you have to surround it with a try-catch block and call commit and rollback od the PlatformTransactionManager in it. I will be looking for more examples and detailed definitions still. But have a look at it please, hope it helps.

Comment: I would like transaction will be auto rollback if there is exception. As link above, using PlatformTransactionManager, I will rollback transaction by hand on each function.

Comment: I couldn't find any other way around. :/

Comment: Thanks for your support, Red fx.